# runtime package installation in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am using delphi 5 and have installed some custom components. When I try to open a form from the IDE I am getting the following error:

> Class TdxButtonEdit not found. dxEdit.bpl package contains that
>   TdxButtonEdit.

dxEdit.bpl is runtime package, how to install it? When I try I am getting the error:

> Cant install because its not design time package.

Comment: Runtime-only packages cannot be installed in the IDE. You need to find and install the corresponding designtime package.

Comment: any suggestion how to find corresponding designtime package? I m having more than 100 packages.

Comment: The documentation that came with the components? If none, the company/developer that provides the components, or the component's web site would probably be next. Since we don't know what dxEdit is (it could be anything, because you can name your own packages anything as long as they don't conflict with another package installed in your Delphi configuration), it's pretty hard to say where the designtime package might be or what it might be called. You might look for something like `dxEditD`, for instance, where the final 'D' means it's design-time. You might also try `dxEditD_D5`.

Comment: The most common designtime package prefix is DCL (dcldxEditXX.bpl), but a D suffix is also common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TdxButtonEdit` is from an old DevExpress Library because the new one as changed to `TcxButtonEdit` and is part of the ExpressEditors. They aren't free but for me are the best VCL components, very rich and powerful and great on support. You don't have any dcldxEdit.bpl?

Comment: Yes its part of ExpressEditors. I will check that dcldxEdit.bpl is there or not.